# Getting the longest string in an array of strings that could be multiline?

Tags: javascript

Suppose the following:

```
const arrayOfString = [
    'Hello!',
    `The quick brown fox
    jumps over the lazy

    dog`,
    'And then went home'
];
```

How can I get the longest line in such an array? Here's what I've got going for me, but I fear that this is the least performant approach:

```
let longestRow = 0;
arrayOfString.forEach((str) => {
    const splitStr = str.split('\n');

    splitStr.forEach((str) => {
        const strLen = str.trim().length;
        if (strLen > longestRow) {
            console.log(`>${str}<`, strLen);
            longestRow = strLen;
        }
    })
});
```

```js
const arrayOfString = [
  'Hello!',
  `The quick brown fox
    jumps over the lazy

    dog`,
  'And then went home'
];
let longestRow = 0;

arrayOfString.forEach((str) => {
  const splitStr = str.split('\n');

  splitStr.forEach((str) => {
    const strLen = str.trim().length;
    if (strLen > longestRow) {
      console.log(`>${str}<`, strLen);
      longestRow = strLen;
    }
  })
});
```

There also seems to be a problem with template literals, because I need to use `trim()` to get the true length of each string.

I'd expect `longestRow` to be `19` (because `'The quick brown fox'` is the longest string)

Comment: Do you have an issue with the performance of your approach? If not, keep it simple. Your approach is simple, clear, and working...

Comment: What is wrong with your approach? If you want a "more clean" code then may be post on SE code review.

Comment: Is the sample data representative of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you can get "more performant" than the method you are using, but what I can do is shorten it up into a one-liner:

```js
const arrayOfString = [
    'Hello!',
    `The quick brown fox
    jumps over the lazy

    dog`,
    'And then went home'
];

console.log(
    Math.max(...arrayOfString.flatMap(
        (str) => str.split("\n")
    ).map((line) => line.trim().length))
);
```

Mapping over each string, we split the string by `\n`, then flatten the resulting array with [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap). Then mapping over the new array, we trim each string and get its length. Finally, we pass the array of string lengths to `Math.max` to get the longest length.

---

You could also move the second mapping into the `flatMap`:

```js
const arrayOfString = [
    'Hello!',
    `The quick brown fox
    jumps over the lazy

    dog`,
    'And then went home'
];

console.log(
    Math.max(...arrayOfString.flatMap(
        (str) => str.split("\n").map((line) => line.trim().length)
    ))
);
```

---

If you think this is less performant because it has more nesting, convince yourself otherwise with this snippet:

```js
const arrayOfString = [
    'Hello!',
    `The quick brown fox
    jumps over the lazy

    dog`,
    'And then went home'
];

const lines = arrayOfString.flatMap((str) => str.split("\n"));
const lengths = lines.map((line) => line.trim().length);
const longest = Math.max(...lengths);

console.log(longest);
```

It's clear that there is no unnecessary nesting now.

Comment: Quite elegant, but if I'm not mistaken, this is less performant as you need iterations nested 3 levels (`Max.max`, `flatMap`, `map`) instead of 2.

Comment: @code It isn't 3 levels of nesting. You're just piping an array through two operations.

Comment: Sorry, it's two levels of nesting plus another loop.

Comment: @code I also had some doubts with the performance, so I added a JSBench, and a 3rd snippet that shows why it isn't 3 levels of nesting.

Comment: I also ended up going down a rabbit hole and decided to expand on your example with `flatMap`. Not sure exactly how to read the results generated over at JSBench, but it marks the following as the fastest: `arrayOfString.flatMap((el) => el.split('\n').map(el => el.trim())).sort((a,b) => b.length - a.length)[0].length`

Comment: Remove the console.logs from all cases then compare the results. The speed of OPs original code will surprise you. Such is the case with "faster way of doing what's already working" questions.

Comment: @SalmanA I did, just now, and got practically the same results. All the cases in the linked jsbench had `console.log`, so I didn't expect much change when I removed them. Was there something else that you meant?

Comment: @vr there's a console.log in the body of the inner forEach, did you get that one?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't want to create an account on jsbench but this is what I see https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FJiy.png. Your answer is MUCH slower than original hence my point that upvotes don't matter; people just vote for the answer that looks more fancy.

Comment: @BenStephens You're right. I did forget to remove the log inside the forEach and now I see the same result.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably use for of loops to speed things up a bit without losing the current readability or changing your current code much:

```js
const arrayOfString = [
    'Hello!',
    `The quick brown fox
    jumps over the lazy

    dog`,
    'And then went home'
];

let longest = 0;

for(const string of arrayOfString) {
  for(const line of string.split("\n")) {
    const len = line.trim().length;
    if(len > longest)
      longest = len;
  }
}

console.log(longest);
```

A slightly trimmed down version could look like:

```
let longest = 0;

for(const string of arrayOfString) {
  for(const line of string.split("\n")) {
    longest = Math.max(line.trim().length, longest);
  }
}
```

**Edit**: Adding this to @vr's JSBench with the inner console.log() from the original removed and this is slightly slower (which is a bit surprising to me). (I would still use this version as (to me) it's a bit easier to read, but that wasn't the question.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` to simplify your code:

```js
const arrayOfString = [
  "Hello!",
  `The quick brown fox
    jumps over the lazy

    dog`,
  "And then went home",
]

const longestRow = arrayOfString.reduce((prev, cur) => {
  const currentGreatest = cur
    .split("\n")
    .reduce((a, b) => ((b = b.trim().length), b > a ? b : a), 0)
  return currentGreatest > prev ? currentGreatest : prev
}, 0)

console.log(longestRow)
```

Regarding performance, I've written a custom benchmark. On my device, the average results place this code as fastest, the original code second, and the other answer third.

```js
// original solution
function a(arr) {
  let longestRow = 0;
  arr.forEach((str) => {
    const splitStr = str.split('\n');

    splitStr.forEach((str) => {
      const strLen = str.trim().length;
      if (strLen > longestRow) {
        longestRow = strLen;
      }
    })
  });
  return longestRow;
}

// other answer
function b(arr) {
  const lines = arr.flatMap((str) => str.split("\n"));
  const lengths = lines.map((line) => line.trim().length);
  return Math.max(...lengths);
}

// this answer
function c(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((prev, cur) => {
    const currentGreatest = cur
      .split("\n")
      .reduce((a, b) => ((b = b.trim().length), b > a ? b : a), 0)
    return currentGreatest > prev ? currentGreatest : prev
  }, 0)
}

function fakeData() {
  const chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890\n".split("")
  const result = []
  const iters = (Math.random() * 50) | 0
  for(let i = 0; i < iters; i++) {
    result.push(Array.from({ length: (Math.random() * 100) | 0 }, (_, i) => chars[(Math.random() * chars.length) | 0]).join(""))
  }
  return result
}

const data = Array.from({ length: 5000 }, fakeData)

console.time("a")
for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
  a(data[i])
console.timeEnd("a")

console.time("b")
for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
  b(data[i])
console.timeEnd("b")

console.time("c")
for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
  c(data[i])
console.timeEnd("c")
```

Comment: Nicely done, this is faster than mine [by 20%](https://jsbench.me/x6lfa1hpgb/3). Surprised to see that nested reduce is faster, but still, it isn't as short as mine .

Comment: @vr. I think the difference lies in the fact that you have to make a separate call to `Math.max()` _after_ all the code is executed, while this solution evaluates the greatest value _during_ iteration, probably avoiding an additional partial iteration.

Comment: @vr. apologies for the spam, but I also noticed what you said about the nested reduce; I think it's the fact that `flatMap` at face value gives it a linear performance look, but I'm not sure if it saves much, if any, against just a nested loop.